# How can a JACC provider use the Principal-to-role mapping facilities of the server it's deployed on?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, authorization, jacc

I am writing a `JACC` provider.

Along the way, this means implementing a [`PolicyConfiguration`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/security/jacc/PolicyConfiguration.html).

The `PolicyConfiguration` is responsible for accepting configuration information from the application server, such as which permissions accrue to which roles.  This is so that a [`Policy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html) later on can make authorization decisions when handed [information about the current user](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html) and what he's trying to do.

However, it is not part of the `PolicyConfiguration`'s (atrocious) contract to maintain a mapping between roles and their permissions, and `Principals` that are assigned to those roles.

Typically--always, really--an application server houses this mapping.  For example, on Glassfish, you affect this mapping by supplying things like `sun-web.xml` and `sun-ejb-jar.xml` and so on with your Java EE modules.  (These vendor-specific files are responsible for saying, e.g., `superusers` is a group that is to be assigned the application role of `admins`.)

I would like to reuse the functionality these files supply, and I would like to do so for as wide an array of application servers as possible.

Here is--totally arbitrarily--IBM's take on the matter, which appears to confirm my suspicion that what [I want to do is essentially impossible](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/csec_jaccextensions.html). (More ammunition for my case that this particular Java EE contract is not worth the paper it's printed on.)

**My question:** how do I get at this principal-to-role-mapping information in--for starters--Glassfish and JBoss from within a `PolicyConfiguration`?  If there's a standard way to do it that I'm unaware of, I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this issue? I'd like to write a JACC provider too, and also a JASPIC authentication provider in order to build portable web applications...

Comment: This doesn't sound very promising either: `Because JSR-115 does not define how to address role mapping, WebLogic JACC classes are used for role-to-principal mapping.` See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24485/server_prot.htm#SCPRG401

Comment: My take on this at the moment is that you have to always make sure your JACC provider is coupled to a JASPIC provider that you are therefore also obligated to write.  I haven't gone this route yet but it's on my table to try.

Comment: @LairdNelson, if you have time, you should probably write up an answer around your JASPIC comment. This sounds promising, and there's a 300 reputation bounty on this question.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what you have in mind with the JASPIC/JACC combo. As far as I can see, with JASPIC you use a `GroupPrincipalCallback` which normally suffers from the same mandatory role mapping. But if JACC can do something here that it can't do for a proprietary module, then it would be interesting to share.

Comment: Hi; not trying to keep anyone in suspense. :-) I don't have an answer here that I could whip up in a hurry.  I just recall Ron Monzillo advising me that the only way to get principal-to-role assignments "into" a JACC provider in a way that it can understand is to have the JASPIC implementation effectively coupled to it.

Comment: you could simply parse the config file, but that would limit you to a specific application server, and/but it might be possible to determine which server you run on, or check for the different files...

Comment: Have you tried [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beacr.html)?

Comment: One more piece of information related to this. From the JEUS 7 security manual: `The JACC interface does not contain any implementation related to principal-to-role mapping, but only for role-to-resource mapping. The user must implement a separate JEUS-specific interface to implement the mapping, and JEUS provides the isjeus.security.impl.aznrep.JACCPrincipalRoleMapper interface for this purpose.`

Comment: Looking at JACC anew I wonder if we could do something like this in the specification without requiring new code or even a maintenance release: What If It Were Mandated that if you passed in a delimited set of principal names as a `String` to `PolicyContext#getContext(String)` and were assured that you would get back a `Set<String>` of corresponding roles if there were an appropriate policy context handler installed for that key?  No new interfaces, no backwards compatibility issues. No grosser than the existing `String` parsing that is already required for `EJBMethodPermission`.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: there's no standard way to do it.

Although Glassfish and JBoss support principal-to-role mappings, JACC does no assume all containers do, and so it delegates the responsibility of keeping those mappings to the JACC provider implementation. From the docs (see: [`PolicyConfiguration.addToRole` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/security/jacc/PolicyConfiguration.html#addToRole%28java.lang.String,%20java.security.Permission%29)):

> It is the job of the Policy provider to ensure that all the
>   permissions added to a role are granted to principals "mapped to the
>   role".

In other words, you need to implement that yourself inside your JACC provider for each container. For JBoss, for example, you could use one of the subclasses of [`AbstractRolesMappingProvider`](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/API_Documentation/files/javadoc/org/jboss/security/mapping/providers/role/AbstractRolesMappingProvider.html).

Comment: As an aside, a portable provider could choose to ignore container role mapping; it could e.g assume that any principal implies an application role of the same name, unless the application somehow (via a `PolicyContextHandler` specifically registered by the provider for that purpose, for instance) conveys otherwise. Another provider could as well disregard the notion of roles altogether (and hence the container-provided `PolicyConfiguration`), instead operating solely on (application-provided) principal-to-permission mappings (and where those permissions need not be limited to JACC's ones).

Comment: Side note #2: As of Java EE 8, 1:1 group-to-role mapping has become the new default (which however only gets us halfway there, as roles must still be statically declared upfront -- assuming no custom JACC provider is in effect).