# migrate Java EE Application to LDAP

Tags: jakarta-ee, active-directory, ldap

I have some questions about LDAP (ActiveDirectory) and an existing Java EE Application.

In our Java EE Application we have an mix in our permission handling. So sometimes we ask `isUserInRole("rolename")` and sometimes we ask `hasUserPermission("permission)`.

Now, we want to bind this existing application to an LDAP, and I have no clue how a LDAP works ;-)
So I have a few questions:

1. Can a LDAP only works withs groups, or also with permissions?
2. Where do I store the permissions? in LDAP or in my application database
3. where do i the mapping between groups and permissions? (ldap or application)
4. Do I need to use JAAS when using LDAP with my Java EE Application?

I hope you can help me with these hopefully simple questions!

Comment: There are two ways in which I could interpret your first question: a) *"by what means can an LDAP-compliant directory **itself** perform access control, i.e., how can it restrict unauthorized operations from being performed on its **own** data?"*, and b) *"can Java EE solely authorize a caller based on its groups (when stored in an LDAP-compliant directory), or also based on its permissions?"*. Given the context you probably mean (b) but I believe it's not clear enough.

Comment: Also, what's a *permission* in your use case? A mere `String`? A `java.security.Permission`? Something else? And how is `hasUserPermission(String) implemented? Does it interact with the Java EE security model?

Comment: Sorry, for being unspecific.
1. How should a JEE app restrict users for doing some things with the help of a LDAP? 
2. permission is a String, no it doesn't interact with the Java Security model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Note: Wherever the term *LDAP* is used below, an *LDAP-compliant directory service* is what is actually being referred to.</sub>

> 1. How should a JEE app restrict users for doing some things with the help of a LDAP?

The Java EE security model remains, with respect to authorization, (predominantly) role-based (not to be confused with *RBAC*); at the end of the day the runtime will still authorize your users (*callers* in general) based on their application-level roles, regardless of *where* (LDAP, relational DB, SAML IdP, XML file, whatever) and *how* (i.e., as which SQL types, LDAP attribute types, etc.) those are persisted. In fact, some applications may not externally store their callers' role memberships at all, but calculate them during authentication instead, based on other attributes of the respective caller; an authentication mechanism might, as a contrived example, "see" that caller `uid=jdoe, dc=users, dc=some, dc=org` has a `hireDate` attribute that refers to a date more than 3 years in the past, and a `jobTitle` attribute of *developer*, thereby inferring that `jdoe` is a *senior developer*, assigning that as an actual role.

> 2. Where do I store the permissions? in LDAP or in my application database?

> 3. where do i the mapping between groups and permissions? (ldap or application)

First of all, your notion of a *permission* is not a good fit for the Java EE security model, thus my suggestion would be to drop permissions altogether and use corresponding roles directly. The benefit of doing so should be obvious: you can move from programmatic to purely declarative authorization, as the runtime would now be enabled to handle all authorization checks for you. Note that you are in no way mandated to think of roles solely as an equivalent to *user groups*; while they can indeed express something as coarse-grained as "editor" and "can-view-stats-panel", they can also express something as fine-grained as "can-access-method-void-getBonus(BigDecimal)-of-instance-123-of-EJB-BonusGranter-with-arg-not-greater-than-100$-during-working-hours-every-13th-of-every-January-between-08:00:10Z-and-08:01:09Z-if-hardworking-and-weather's-sunny-and-manager's-in-a-good-mood" (you would obviously have to come up with a good convention to be able to express all that both compactly and intuitively, but you get the idea).

There is also a spec called *JACC* which your Java EE product may or may not support. If you *absolutely* require more flexibility than what roles can offer, you could theoretically take advantage of it, as it essentially would allow you to use the Java SE `Policy` in order to determine--on the basis of `Principal`-assigned low-level, seemingly infinitely flexible `java.security.Permission`s--whether a caller indeed has a role. Regardless, the goal remains the same: separation of authorization-related code from business logic.

As for your actual two questions--and that should not only hold true for your permissions (if you wish to retain them), but for most of your persistent data--my simplistic answer would be that if the data in question is needed (or the probability of it being depended on in the foreseeable future is high) by other applications, and it *can* "fit" into a directory information tree (not necessarily the case), then it may be stored in LDAP. Otherwise, it should be stored "closer" to the application, e.g. in the application's "dedicated" DB, as you suggested. Also keep in mind that, at least traditionally, LDAP is (was) considered to be a poor choice of repository for storage of data with a low *read-to-write ratio*. I do not know to what extent--if at all--that performance consideration remains valid at present, but I would still not use LDAP for persisting highly dynamic data, like a web service's response time or availability percentage.

> 4. Do I need to use JAAS when using LDAP with my Java EE Application?

You do and should *not* have to (directly) rely on JAAS either for authentication or authorization in Java EE. The subject has been extensively discussed elsewhere, hence I will not elaborate it here. In order to leverage container-managed authorization, as addressed earlier, you still have to use container-managed authentication, the main purpose of which is to establish the identity (*caller* and *group* (role) `Principal`s) of your callers with the runtime. Now, ideally you would just declare something like the following

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <LDAP-identity-store>
        <base-DN>dc=users, dc=some, dc=org</base-DN>
        <bind-DN>uid=admin</bind-DN>
        <bind-credential>
            <credential-alias ref="admin_LDAP_pass"/>
        </bind-credential>
        <base-search-DN>dc=users, dc=some, dc=org</base-search-DN>
        <search-filter>(uid={username_HTTP_param})</search-filter>
    </LDAP-identity-store>
</login-config>
```

in your `web.xml` and authentication would *just* work. Unfortunately that is not the case for Java EE (at least as of version 7, as some much-promising changes in this area are expected to be included in the platform's next release). Assuming that you still want to use container-managed authentication, you have two options:

a) Author a portable authentication mechanism using JASPIC. Your `javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule` would basically:

1. connect to and authenticate your caller (i.e. its form-`POST`ed username) against the LDAP, and if successful,
2. retrieve (and/or compute) the caller's roles (called *groups* at that point),
3. instantiate a `Principal` representation of the authenticated caller,
4. instantiate a `String[]` of *group* names (off of which the runtime will construct corresponding *group* `Principal`s), and finally
5. communicate the outcome of the previous two steps to the runtime via JASPIC-specific `javax.security.Callback`s.

Advantages: Supported on all Full Java EE Profile implementations as well as on Jetty and Tomcat (since 9.0.0.M4).
Drawbacks: Requires a bit of effort and is not always optimally supported.

b) Author a vendor-specific authentication extension, JAAS-based or otherwise, essentially completing the same steps, although via proprietary APIs.

Advantages: Often zero new code (and certainly less boilerplate) needs to be written.
Drawbacks: Non-portable approach.

---

Further reading:

- If you feel intimidated by LDAP (I know I used to!), fear not, things eventually get better. :) In case you don't feel like reading 10+ RFCs on day 1 (you should though, eventually), there are countless of great resources online. Here are just a few (non-Active Directory-specific ones) which helped me in the past:

  - [Brad Marshall - Introduction to LDAP](http://quark.humbug.org.au/publications/ldap/ldap_tut_v2.pdf)
  - [ZYTRAX - LDAP for Rocker Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/)
  - [Andrew Findlay's articles / papers on LDAP](https://www.skills-1st.co.uk/dir/)
  - [Peter Gietz - LDAP - concepts, applications, practical problems](http://daasi.de/pub/DAASI_2003-08-09_LDAP-conceptsv3.pdf)
  - [JNDI as an LDAP API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/jndi.html) (and the JNDI tutorial in general)
- JACC:

  - [Laird Nelson - JACC condensed](https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/jacc-condensed/)
  - Arjan Tijms's series of articles on JACC:

    - [Implementing container authorization in Java EE with JACC](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/03/implementing-container-authorization-in.html)
    - [Java EE authorization - JACC revisited part I](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/12/java-ee-authorization-jacc-revisited.html)
    - [Java EE authorization - JACC revisited part II](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/01/java-ee-authorization-jacc-revisited.html)
    - [Java EE authorization - JACC revisited part III](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/03/java-ee-authorization-jacc-revisited.html)
  - [How can a JACC provider use the Principal-to-role mapping facilities of the server it's deployed on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822410/how-can-a-jacc-provider-use-the-principal-to-role-mapping-facilities-of-the-serv) (JACC's greatest shortcoming)
- On JAAS in Java EE (many more SO posts on the matter, just search for questions tagged [`jaas` + `java-ee`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaas+java-ee))

  - [Arjan Tijms - JAAS in Java EE is not the universal standard you may think it is](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/02/jaas-in-java-ee-is-not-universal.html) (also make sure you read the two referenced articles by Raymond K. NG)
  - [Is JAAS security in Java EE based web application server dependent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202590/is-jaas-security-in-java-ee-based-web-application-server-dependent)
- JASPIC (more SO posts, search for [jaspic](/questions/tagged/jaspic))

  - [Arjan Tijms's JASPIC ZEEF Page](https://jaspic.zeef.com/arjan.tijms)
  - [OmniSecurity](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnisecurity)
  - [Hook on process where container asks for roles of LDAP user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280403/hook-on-process-where-container-asks-for-roles-of-ldap-user) (an introductory JASPIC - LDAP sample of mine; not 100% correct but mostly functional)

Comment: Thx for the very detailed answer! 
Look's like a hard way for me, to migrate from a custom (self-written) authentication/authorization mechanism to a standard one...

Comment: @mananana I don't think Java EE security per se is hard--at least not as hard as familiarizing oneself with LDAP can be, imho. Migration can of course be time-consuming. I only suggested staying with "native" Java EE authZ because it sounded as if you were already using it to some degree (you mentioned (`HttpServletRequest`#)`isUserInRole(String)`), which means you're using container-managed authN too, even if only indirectly. If that's not the case then I got it all wrong from the very beginning, and transitioning from fully "homegrown" to "native" is indeed likely to be overkill.